# AWS codeartifact copy version and choose desired version name in destination repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-cli, aws-codeartifact

Code artifact,

I want to copy a maven package version from repository A to repository B . I want to choose the version name in the destination repository.

I tried this command and it did the copy but i can't choose the version name.

```
aws codeartifact copy-package-versions --domain mydomain --domain-owner 123456789012 --namespace mynamespace --source-repository repoA --destination-repository repoB --format maven --package mypackage --versions 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Any idea or workarounds please?